# Difference between Auto layouts and Size Classes

Tags: ios, autolayout, xcode6, size-classes

I have found some posts describing difference between when to use Auto layouts and When to use Size classes.

But still I am not able to understand the difference between these two.

If any one can suggest the difference or share a good link.

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: you can get some idea from here ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638898/difference-between-use-auto-layout-and-use-size-class-in-xcode-6-1

Comment: Please refer to already asked question on below link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638898/difference-between-use-auto-layout-and-use-size-class-in-xcode-6-1

Answer (score 5):

Size classes is used when we design app more than devices to make alignment of elements according to device design.like portrait and landscape design differ to each other.
[image]

Auto Layout is needed. In Storyboard, you place a button right in the center of the view. Run the app on both iPhone Retina (3.5-inch) and iPhone Retina (4-inch) simulators. basically its used for same alignment on different size device.

[image]